# Where should I ask software architecture / design questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I often look for feedback about the design/software architecture for a given problem. Should I ask it on Stack Overflow, or is there a separate site that is dedicated for such things?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260) is the place for you.

And if any one says otherwise tell them to read the [on topic help section](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and that [I sent you](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf).

Comment: This was helpful! Can I also ask questions about database modelling in Programmers ? (sample question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505168/how-do-i-model-this-in-database)

Comment: @brainydexter - They might be better asked on [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll flag the question for moderation now.

Comment: Why you wiki this?

Comment: @Won't I've been wiking all my answers for quite a while now.

Comment: @ChrisF: You should just take that rep and spend it on bountying stuff you like.

Comment: @Won't - Bountying questions that only devs can answer turned out to be a bit pointless. You're right I *should* look for good answers to reward.

Comment: @Karel the name has changed (I must update this answer) and the scope has been tightened, but design questions are still on topic.